# Angular 2 - Basic form validation not working anymore

Tags: html, forms, angular, validation

I have an angular 2 application which contains a basic form with inputs and basic html validation. Something like:

```
<form (onSubmit)="submit()">
  <input type="email" />
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

This worked about a week or two ago. Today, I was testing my application and noticed that it's completely ignoring any basic validation like type, pattern, max, min, etc.
In this case, it should complain when you type in a value without the @ symbol. However, it isn't complaining anymore. You can type whatever you want in the input field.

Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: Please show us more code, this is just a (almost) plain HTML form, although if you enter something in the "email" field any recent browser should do the email verification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having this issue too. So I searched and found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13566).

Basically by default angular is adding something called **novalidate**.
If you guys want to use browser's native form validation just add **ngNativeValidate** attribute:

```
<form ngNativeValidate></form>
```

Comment: `[noValidate]="false"` in 2023